# internet lock out software

Tags: internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make it as difficult as possible to connect to the Internet from my “work computer”?](https://superuser.com/questions/32728/how-can-i-make-it-as-difficult-as-possible-to-connect-to-the-internet-from-my-wo)

Is there any software that locks out internet access on my computer for a fixed time and won't unlock even if my life depended on it ?

Comment: The hardware solution would be a hammer or a padlock and a cage

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/32728/how-can-i-make-it-as-difficult-as-possible-to-connect-to-the-internet-from-my-wo

Comment: @trolle3000: radio-frequency shielded cage to block WiFi.

Comment: Why not just use self-control?

Answer (score 1):

Your router most likely has controls to handle this.

Comment: The problem is if he has the password the router then its trivial to circumvent.  If user is serious about enforcing this, then he needs to have third party administer the router.

Comment: The other problem with a router is you can just bypass it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly make use of parental control software or firewall software so long as someone else that is trustworthy not to give in is the one with the admin password.

Answer (score 0):

Look like it impossible. Boot LiveCD and access internet directly always possible. Or reinstall OS.

*"What one man build, that other man always can destroy."*

Especial when it is one man in both cases.

You can only make some troubles for himself in getting access to internet.
If laziness is overpower the desire then system can working.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the DNS to 0.0.0.0 and that would basically kill the internet for most common users, without killing network connections, unless your network depended on DNS.

Comment: DNS Caching pretty much prevents this solution from working. Yes, you might block new sites that the user hasn't visited yet, but most machines will still be able to surf commonly used websites for a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is completely what you want, but [K9 Web Protection](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/) is a child's (or children's) web filtering and blocking software that is *extremely* configurable.  You could turn off all the settings that you didn't want (filtering, word block, site block, category block), and just use the Internet time feature.  You can set what hours of the day you want the Internet on the computer to be blocked, and can customize each day of the week.  All settings are accessed via the web browser, and are protected by a password, which you could give to someone else and not know yourself if you wanted to completely block access.  It works cross-browsers; one configuration covers Internet Explorer, Firefox, and others all one the same machine.

K9 Web Protection: http://www1.k9webprotection.com/

Did I mention that it is FREE?

Comment: This is partly an expansion of @BBlake's post above.  His point about a trustworthy person is very true.