# Software to restrict web browsing to allow for productivity?

Tags: google-chrome, internet, browser-addons, productivity

I check my e-mails too much. And from time to time I find a webpage that I keep checking too much (a forum thread and the likes).

What tools can I use to restrict my access to these pages?

(I use Windows XP with Google Chrome.)

Comment: How about discipline and self control?

Comment: Why not couple that with external help?

Comment: what about this makes it not a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/13271/how-to-overcome-procrastination-and-cyber-slacking or http://superuser.com/questions/32728/how-can-i-make-it-as-difficult-as-possible ?

Comment: ^Perhaps the user who asked this hadn't joined the site when those questions were asked. And he could have performed a search (e.g. http://superuser.com/search?q=restrict+web+browsing+for+productivity ) and not found those questions. Just say it's a dupe; ask him to search more thoroughly; and save the attitude for your whipping boy or something.

Comment: Hello Quack.

The first post wasn't relevant.  The second was, I didn't find it with a search, but even after reading through it - I can't say it has a solution I want to have.  Greg solution so far is better.  Although that addon is still a bit immature.  Lese, thanks for the support!

Answer (score 2):

There are extensions in Chrome for [blocking websites](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji) to increase your productivity. You might also want to try the [desktop](https://www.rescuetime.com/) or [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/cnggaadmcamdjiimdhelidfgolafbiej#) version of RescueTime. I haven't use the Chrome version, but the desktop version does have a ["Get Focused"](http://blog.rescuetime.com/2009/08/19/turning-off-the-distracting-parts-of-the-internet/) feature to help you stay on track.